# Cannot convert undefined or null to object after compile

Tags: openzeppelin-sdk

My smart contract project has been initialised with `oz init` and I have a single contract. After running `oz compile` I get an error saying `Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

complete output of `oz compile`:

```
✖ Compiling contracts with solc 0.8.4 (commit.c7e474f2)
Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

It is not a compilation error. If there is a compilation problem, this will be shown in the expected way.

In order to segregate the sources of error, I have created an empty project with just one contract.

#### environment

- MacOS Big Sur 11.2.3 (20D91)
- node v14.13.0
- npm 6.14.7

The folder content is:

- .openzeppelin

  - project.json
- contracts

  - token.sol
- networks.js
- node_modules
- package-lock.json
- package.json

#### project.json

```
{
  "manifestVersion": "2.2",
  "contracts": {},
  "dependencies": {},
  "name": "net2u-token",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "compiler": {
    "compilerSettings": {
      "optimizer": {}
    },
    "typechain": {
      "enabled": false
    }
  },
  "telemetryOptIn": true
}
```

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "token",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "oz compile && mocha --exit --recursive test"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@openzeppelin/cli": "^2.8.2",
    "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

#### token.sol

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Net4uToken is Ownable, ERC20 {
    constructor (string memory name_, string memory symbol_) ERC20(name_, symbol_) Ownable() {}
}
```

#### networks.js

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      protocol: 'http',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 8545,
      gas: 5000000,
      gasPrice: 5e9,
      networkId: '*',
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can compile using solc 0.7.5 and `npx oz compile`.

### token.sol :

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.7.5;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Net4uToken is Ownable, ERC20 {
    constructor (string memory name_, string memory symbol_) ERC20(name_, symbol_) Ownable() {}
}
```

### project.json :

```
{
  "manifestVersion": "2.2",
  "contracts": {},
  "dependencies": {},
  "name": "net2u-token",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "compiler": {
    "compilerSettings": {
      "optimizer": {
        "enabled": false,
        "runs": "200"
      }
    },
    "typechain": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "manager": "openzeppelin",
    "solcVersion": "0.7.5",
    "artifactsDir": "build/contracts",
    "contractsDir": "contracts"
  },
  "telemetryOptIn": false
}
```

I also changed the `@openzeppelin/contracts` package version to match solc 0.7.5 using : `npm i @openzeppelin/contracts@3.4.0`.

I cannot compile with solc 0.7.6 and 0.8.x releases and I get the same error as you : `Cannot convert undefined or null to object`.

I also tried to compile the example smart contract from the [doc](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/cli/2.8/getting-started) and that's the same scenario : I can compile with 0.7.5 but not with more recent solc versions.

This is likely due to the fact OpenZeppelin SDK is no longer maintained.
From their doc :

> OpenZeppelin SDK is not being actively developed. We recommend using [Upgrades Plugins](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/) instead. For more information, see [Building for interoperability](https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/building-for-interoperability-why-we-re-focusing-on-upgrades-plugins/4088): why we’re focusing on Upgrades Plugins.

Comment: This worked for me also, thank you.